# does nservicebus serviceInsight only work nservicebus 4?

Tags: nservicebus, serviceinsight

We are using nservicebus 3.3.5, and the Endpoint Explorer doesn't show anything after I connect to `http://localhost:33333/api/`.

Is there any documentation beside the introductory video?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the endpoint forwarding messages to an audit queue?  ServiceInsight will read off of that to get information about the endpoint.

Comment: No, I don't. I couldn't find any doc anywhere.

Comment: Take a look at the 4.0 example app.configs.  You'll see some notes on the audit feature supporting SI.

Comment: Thanks! You answer is equally good. I can only mark one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Endpoint explorer in ServiceInsight uses the api that's provided by ServiceControl, which is part of NSB 4.0. It doesn't mean that you can not use ServiceInsight on previous versions of NSB, you can still use Queue Explorer, which would give you things like formatted message payload, exception information, headers, and Return To Source functionality.